# Convergence with respect to bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to prove that

Let $N$ be the Newtonian potential.
We observe first that $N$ is a bounded mapping from $L^p(\Omega)$ into itself for $1\le p<\infty$.

Consider the case $p=2$, by approximation, if we have a sequence $(f_n)\subset C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ which converges to $f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, then $(Nf_n)$ converges to $Nf$ in $W^{2,2}(\Omega)$.

In particular, I cannot explain why the convergence of the 'image' seguence is in $W^{2,2}$.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why should that be true? In general, $Nf$ need not even be an element of $W^{2,2}$.

Comment: Functional always means that the image is in a field $\mathbb{K} \in \lbrace \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\rbrace$. So functional from $L^2(\Omega)$ to itself makes no sense. And is $\Omega$ bounded?

Comment: You are right! Sorry, I had made some mistakes! I edited the question...